# Does weight lifting burn calories?

Tags: nutrition

I've started following [this](http://scoobysworkshop.com/advanced-workout-plan/) weight lifting routine and have adjusted my intake of protein to suit. Should I also be eating more calories in general or do I only need to think about cardio for this?

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide your workout plan here instead of just linking to it?

Comment: It is technically possible.

Comment: What I meant was that a link in itself hides the relevant information that people would need to formulate a proper answer. It would be due diligence to provide the necessary information here should the link content change or disappear over time. It provides one less step for everyone to do and benefits the community at large here. Doing so will create a good, cohesive space question/answer combination here on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weight lifting is great for building muscle. Having more muscle mass has been said as a means of increasing your basal metabolism; therefore burning calories:

> Strength training has an added benefit for weight loss in addition to
>   just burning calories. It will raise your muscle metabolism during the
>   exercise session and continue for a long time afterward, even days
>   following high-intensity workouts..

Read more: http://www.livestrong.com/article/256854-calories-burned-through-strength-training/#ixzz1xgfFH1id

In terms of your other questions about calorie intake and nutritional needs. It really depends on your fitness goals. I'll go ahead and make some broad general assumptions.

If you're just starting off and you're looking to lose weight there are zounds approaches and philosophies: limiting caloric/carbohydrate intake, changing the frequency and spacing of meals, etc.

Also, i would recommend reviewing some threads here on this Fitness.SE:

- [Cardio vs. Weight lifting. Which one is better for losing weight?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/cardio-vs-weight-lifting-which-one-is-better-for-losing-weight)
- [Theory to burn Calories with muscle](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2954/theory-to-burn-calories-with-muscle)
- [Calories to consume on workout days](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/4791/calories-to-consume-on-workout-days)

Answer (score 1):

Weight lifting is work. Work requires calories.

Think of it this way: just being *alive* burns calories.

Being alive *and* lifting heavy things will burn *more* calories, because you're doing *more* work.

Whether or not you *should* be eating more calories depends on what you're trying to do.

If you're trying to *maintain* weight, and you've *increased* your caloric expenditure, you would need to *increase* your caloric intake to keep pace. If you're trying to *lose* or *gain* weight, you'd need to *adjust* your caloric intake to match your targeted loss/gain pace.

Comment: but how do I know how many calories I burn from a specific weight session? Can I estimate somehow?

Comment: @SirYakalot Sure, same way you estimate calories for any other activity.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no digital readouts on my weights like there is on cardio equipement. How do you estimate?

Comment: @SirYakalot Look it up online and guesstimate--that's all the machines do, although they're likely a bit more accurate when they have an HR monitor.